# Pyramid login user

Tags: python, pyramid

I don't understand how I can create user sessions with Pyramid. So, how can I create a mechanism for session authentication for a user with `Beaker`? Is `remember` and `authenticated_userid` needed if I'm using beaker (memcached as session storage)?

**Update:**

Login and edit scenario

```
if 'user_id' in request.session:
   # already logged in redirect

# parse post data    
if user.validate_user(username, password):
   request.session['user_id'] = username
   # redirect success

# example edit permission on article
articleId = article.get()['id']
if request.session['user_id'] == articleId:
   # action allowed
```

Comment: You only need to set `Beaker` as your session backend using `pyramid_beaker` and use sessions and authorization in exactly the same way as you did without `Beaker`. Pyramid includes definition of interface for sessions' backends and `pyramid_beaker` implements it using `Beaker` sessions and caching library. As long as you and your sessions' backend follow the interface your app is completely independent from sessions' implementation.

Comment: @zaquest so would the scenario I posted be a reasonably secure authentication and authorisation scheme?

Comment: I think the scenario you posted is reasonably secure. But with `pyramid`'s authentication&authorization (`remember`/`authenticated_userid`) you can do better in third part. You won't need to write `if` expression every time you want to check permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made [a tutorial](http://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.org/en/latest) that covers auth for users new to Pyramid. See if it makes things easier to understand for you. Also with Pyramid authtkt you don't need to bother yourself with saving `session['user_id']` at all.

Comment: if I use SessionAuthenticatePolicy with beaker how can I set 'userid' on the user browser to track it in the next time so that pyramid can extract 'userid' from others next requests from the same user?